# Why can I only have a single Texture binding in my wgpu bind group?

Tags: rust, graphics, webgpu, wgpu-rs

I currently have a [`BindGroup`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.BindGroup.html) and [`BindGroupLayout`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.BindGroupLayout.html) which looks like this:

```rust
let bind_group_layout = device.create_bind_group_layout(&wgpu::BindGroupLayoutDescriptor {
    label: None,
    entries: &[wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
        binding: 0,
        visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::FRAGMENT,
        ty: wgpu::BindingType::Texture {
            sample_type: wgpu::TextureSampleType::Float { filterable: true },
            view_dimension: wgpu::TextureViewDimension::D2,
            multisampled: false,
        },
        count: None,
    }],
});

let bind_group = device.create_bind_group(&wgpu::BindGroupDescriptor {
    label: None,
    entries: &[wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
        binding: 0,
        resource: wgpu::BindingResource::TextureView(&target),
    }],
    layout: &bind_group_layout,
});
```

and works as desired.

For context: I use these in a render pass to do post-processing.

Now I also needed a [`Sampler`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.Sampler.html) in my shader. First I created the `Sampler`

```rust
let linear_sampler = device.create_sampler(&wgpu::SamplerDescriptor {
    mag_filter: wgpu::FilterMode::Nearest,
    min_filter: wgpu::FilterMode::Nearest,
    mipmap_filter: wgpu::FilterMode::Nearest,
    ..Default::default()
});
```

and added it to the layout and bind group like so:

```rust
let bind_group_layout = device.create_bind_group_layout(&wgpu::BindGroupLayoutDescriptor {
    label: None,
    entries: &[
        wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
            binding: 0,
            visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::FRAGMENT,
            ty: wgpu::BindingType::Texture {
                sample_type: wgpu::TextureSampleType::Float { filterable: true },
                view_dimension: wgpu::TextureViewDimension::D2,
                multisampled: false,
            },
            count: None,
        },
        wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
            binding: 1,
            visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::FRAGMENT,
            ty: wgpu::BindingType::Sampler(wgpu::SamplerBindingType::NonFiltering),
            count: None,
        },
    ],
});

let bind_group = device.create_bind_group(&wgpu::BindGroupDescriptor {
    label: None,
    entries: &[
        wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
            binding: 0,
            resource: wgpu::BindingResource::TextureView(&target),
        },
        wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
            binding: 1,
            resource: wgpu::BindingResource::Sampler(&linear_sampler),
        },
    ],
    layout: &bind_group_layout,
});
```

However when I now run my code a get a [ValidationError](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/enum.Error.html#variant.Validation) saying that:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'wgpu error: Validation Error

Caused by:
    In a RenderPass
      note: encoder = `<CommandBuffer-(0, 2, Metal)>`
    In a draw command, indexed:false indirect:false
      note: render pipeline = `<RenderPipeline-(1, 1, Metal)>`
    the pipeline layout, associated with the current render pipeline, contains a bind group layout at index 0 which is incompatible with the bind group layout associated with the bind group at 0
```

I noticed the same behaviour on `Metal` and `DirectX 12`. I also noticed that I get the same error when I only add one sampler or when I add two Texture Bindings as shown below:

```rust
let bind_group_layout = device.create_bind_group_layout(&wgpu::BindGroupLayoutDescriptor {
    label: None,
    entries: &[
        wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
            binding: 0,
            visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::FRAGMENT,
            ty: wgpu::BindingType::Texture {
                sample_type: wgpu::TextureSampleType::Float { filterable: true },
                view_dimension: wgpu::TextureViewDimension::D2,
                multisampled: false,
            },
            count: None,
        },
        wgpu::BindGroupLayoutEntry {
            binding: 1,
            visibility: wgpu::ShaderStages::FRAGMENT,
            ty: wgpu::BindingType::Texture {
                sample_type: wgpu::TextureSampleType::Float { filterable: true },
                view_dimension: wgpu::TextureViewDimension::D2,
                multisampled: false,
            },
            count: None,
        },
    ],
});

let bind_group = device.create_bind_group(&wgpu::BindGroupDescriptor {
    label: None,
    entries: &[
        wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
            binding: 0,
            resource: wgpu::BindingResource::TextureView(&target),
        },
        wgpu::BindGroupEntry {
            binding: 1,
            resource: wgpu::BindingResource::TextureView(&target),
        },
    ],
    layout: &bind_group_layout,
});
```

So the only configuration I found to be working is when the bind group and layout contain exactly one texture binding.

Does anybody have an idea why this is the case here?

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/FrankenApps/wpp/tree/fxaa). The failing code is in `src/fxaa/` and can be tested using `cargo run --example triangle`, the original working code is in `src/grayscale/` and can be run using `cargo run --example text`. I ommited the shaders for brevity and because their contents does not seem to matter, but they can also be found in the repo linked above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `fn resize(&mut self, device: &wgpu::Device, size: &wgpu::Extent3d)`, you have created a new `bind_group` that is incompatible with already binded `bind_group_layout`.

If you recreate a new `bind_group_layout`, you also need to recreate a new pipeline and `pipeline_layout`.